# Is it possible to perform live detection of text typed into textarea in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a "post" button that activates (goes from blurred to colour and from disabled to enabled) when text is typed into the text area.

This works fine but I would like the text area to detect when there is nothing in the text area. So let's say I typed "abc" into the text area.. the submit button would become active but let's say I now delete all the text.. The button is still active.. well not fully as I have this:

```
commentButton.prop({ disabled: commentBox.val() == 0 });
```

Which stops the form from submitting with nothing in the textarea. The issue is the submit button is still in colour and doesn't return back to it's blurred inactive state as expected.

So this brings me to my question..

Can I set up something that will activate and start listening as soon as i focus in the text area and type and know when I've deleted everything from the text area?

This way I can set up an if statement to say if text is all deleted then removeClass for coloured state button and addClass for blurred state button.

Also this should apply to white spaces also.

Here is my current code:

**.comment_box** = my text area

**.activeCommentButton** = coloured submit button

**.commentButton** = blurred submit button

```
$(".microposts").off().on("focus", ".comment_box", function () {
    $(this).prop("rows", 7);
    $(this).parent().find(".activeCommentButton").removeClass("activeCommentButton").addClass("commentButton");
    var commentBox = $(this),
        form = $(this).parent(),
        cancelButton = form.children(".commentButtons").children(".cancelButton"),
        commentButton = form.children(".commentButtons").children(".commentButton");
    $(this).removeClass("comment_box").addClass("comment_box_focused").autoResize();
    form.children(".commentButtons").addClass("displayButtons");
    commentButton.prop({
        disabled: true
    });
    commentBox.off().on("keyup keypress input change", function () {
        commentButton.prop({
            disabled: commentBox.val() == 0
        });
        commentButton.removeClass("commentButton").addClass("activeCommentButton");
    });
    cancelButton.click(function () {
        commentBox.removeClass("comment_box_focused").addClass("comment_box");
        form.children(".commentButtons").removeClass("displayButtons");
        commentBox.val("");
    });
});
```

Kind regards

Comment: `{ disabled: commentBox.val().length == 0 }`

Comment: Can't you just handle "keypress" events and, upon each one, check the length of the `<textarea>` value?

Comment: Could you show me an example if possible? That sounds better than what I'm currently doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes try this, you can modify it:

```
$(".commentButton").prop({ disabled: true });

$(".comment_box").keypress(function() {

    $(".commentButton").prop({ disabled: !$(this).val().length >= 1 })           

});
```

Comment: for having better control on the state of textarea using change event is enough, at least for me, to the extent that i have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but is there a cleaner way?

```
 commentButton.prop({ disabled: true });

                commentBox.off().on("keyup keypress input change", function () {
                  commentButton.prop({ disabled: commentBox.val().length == 0 });
                  if ( commentBox.val().length > 1 ) {
                  commentButton.removeClass("commentButton").addClass("activeCommentButton");
              } else {
                commentButton.removeClass("activeCommentButton").addClass("commentButton");
              }
                });
```

Comment: You should add this to your original post as opposed to posting it as answer... Unless it answers your question - in that case "is there a cleaner way" should be removed too...

Comment: Your entire code is wrong on many levels. Lets start with the fact that you swap around CSS classes like `.activeCommentButton` and `.commentButton` while you really should only do an `addClass("active")`/`removeClass("active")`. You can combine CSS classes, like `.commentButton.active`.

Comment: There's not really any need to track both "keyup" and "keypress", though you might want to add "cut" and "paste".  There's no such thing as an "input" event, I don't think.  The "keypress" fires *after* the key has affected the value of the element, so that's the one you want for keyboard actions.

Comment: Tomalak you would have to see my css and understand my application setup to understand why I'm using addClass/removeClass in the way I am.